# if($_POST['dropdown_value'] == null) is not also returning true if no <option> value was selected

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I have Ajax posting to a php script. One of the posts is a . In the php script, I check if an option in the dropdown was selected. If not, I fill in a default value. This is then submitted to a database. See my below code for checking if an  was selected:

```
if($_POST['dropdownValue'] == null){}
```

99.9% of the time, this works. I don't select an option, and the default value is returned and this is stored in my database. But now I'm finding NULL rows in my database that are filled with the value of `$_POST['dropdownValue']`. Should I be using the `function is_null()?` Or `isset()`? I saw another post that said to check it with `$_POST['dropdownValue'] == ''`. Would that be better?

Comment: Try `!empty()`, it will reject if it's null, 0, an empty string, or not set at all. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why (== null) sometimes fails? I'm just curious.

Comment: @aynber Instead of `!empty()`, just do `$_POST['dropdownValue']`, but I don't think this is the problem here.

Comment: @Dharman Some installations don't like that (usually lower versions of PHP), and will complain about undefined index. Using `!empty` removes that possibility.

Comment: @AMS Not really sure. It should match against 0, empty strings, and empty array, but there could always be something else going on. The comparison chart is at https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 0):

you could try using the isset for this i think

```
if(isset($_POST['dropdownValue']) && ($_POST['dropdownValue'] != null)
{
    'insert that data into my base'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's just use isset:

```
if( isset($_POST['fromPerson']) )
{
   $fromPerson = '+from%3A'.$_POST['fromPerson'];
   echo $fromPerson;
}
```